# Go to link with previous word

Tags: php, header, location

I have this:

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
        if
            ($results['cod'] == $query){             
            header('Location: /shop-'$results['cod']'.html'); 
                }
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }

    }
```

And i wanna go to => webiste.xx/shop-PREVIOUSLY WORD INTRODUCED ($query).html. How can i do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  It might help if you gave us an example, and gave a further explanation of what you mean by "previous word"

Comment: `header('Location: /shop-'.$results['cod'].'.html'); exit;`

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. your header string is not correctly concatenated.

**Change**

```
header('Location: /shop-'$results['cod']'.html');
```

**To**

```
header('Location: /shop-' . $results['cod'] . '.html');
```

and after redirect. don't forget to die or exit your script

```
header('Location: /shop-' . $results['cod'] . '.html');
die;
```